# Getting the height of an absolute div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the height of an absolute div, but am running into a problem. jQuery's .height() doesn't retrieve the correct hei

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're grabbing the wrong element...

```
$('#boxHeight div').first().html($('#box').height());
                                 ----^----
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Y9Upp/6/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/Y9Upp/7/ your selector should be `#box` instead of `#boxheight` ;)